# Store and manipulate GPS locations in a database

Tags: database, geolocation

we are developing a system that tracks the locations of several users. The users upload their locations at a server and then these locations are stored in a database. For now the database is MySQL. We want to make queries like "tell me which users are at a specific square or circle" or "tell me which 5 users are closest to user Tom" etc.

I have the basic knowledge of databases and MySQL but I am not specialized in databases, so as a first thought was to answer the above queries by using MySQL queries and some maths. With a small search I found that there are db systems like PostGIS that include many operations that we need. Especially for PostGIS there are many programs that use it as backend like Quantum GIS that we will be for me very convenient.

My questions now :P

I read that PostGIS is an extension of PostgreSQL, that means that i can use at the same time PostgreSQL for manipulating other data (e.g usernames, time etc) and PostGIS to manipulate the users' locations or I have to create two different databases?

My deadline unfortunately is very tight... So it is easy to pass from MySQL to PostgreSQL or not?

Any other ideas are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should switch to another db engine if you are already using MySQL only for that.

MySQL does support Spatial Data Types like GEOMETRY, POINT, LINESTRING and POLYGON.

see here for the official documentation:

[MySQL Spatial Data Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-spatial-datatypes.html)

if you are using MySQL already and your program works well, explore those data types and try them out, then ask more specific questions when needed ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Tomorrow i will try these types and some functions with them. Now I am searching a tool like Quantum GIS that supports MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a little difficult till you get the hang of things.
You can take a look at http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Things_to_find_out_about_when_moving_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. But as i can see there are many differences so for now i will stay in MySQL